# is there a way to use something like p=product.objects.filter(category=home)?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have some categories that I can filter them by primary key like this :

```
p=product.objects.filter(category=2)
```

but I do not want to bother my self with primary keys I want to filter with exact name of the category not primary key.

I have categories like this :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIvyg.png)

is there a way to use something like `p=product.objects.filter(category=home)` ?

models:

```
class category(models.Model):

    name=models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class product(models.Model):
     
    category = models.ForeignKey(category, related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    image=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    buy=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
product.objects.filter(category__name='home')
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *smallcase*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`product`</s> to `Product`.